# how to disable the place holder on textedit?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, devexpress, textedit

i want to ask, how do i disable the place holder `_` to null or none, also i want to disable the blue thing. i dont know whats its name.

[image]

[image]

for the properties i use this

[image]

when i try to set the place holder to false, its still show the `_` holder.
i prefer via code instead of setting the properties

Comment: eem, what do you mean ?
can u show me by using code?
just disable the holder also the blue thing

Comment: iam using Textedit from devexpress

Comment: Are you sure you using this settings on right textedit? I watch this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6950). Try same text and give me result.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is because you use `masktype=simple`.
Check this [link about simple masktype](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1500).
If value is not entered, automatic write `_`. Look examples on link. This depends of your mask.

Comment: yep, its because of `masktype=simple` that leads too my problem :(
and i find another option that i use the maskedtextbox from the native visual studio itself